# flutter sounds unable to play audio file

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter_sounds package to play audio file.
My audio file exists and is valid file.
For some unknown reason below code is not working and  unable to play the audio.

```
  FlutterSoundPlayer _mPlayer = FlutterSoundPlayer();
try {
          var t = await _mPlayer.openAudioSession();
          print('after open');
    
          print('_mPlayerIsInited');
    
          setState(() async {
            _isPlayerToucher = true;
            _mPlayerIsInited = true;
            _mPlayerisPaused = false;
          });
          
        } catch (e) {
          print('ERROR');
          print(e.toString());
        }

 await _mPlayer.startPlayer(
        fromURI: widget.content,
        whenFinished: () async {
          await _mPlayer.stopPlayer();
          _mPlayer.closeAudioSession();
         
          setState(() {
            _mPlayerIsInited = false;
          });
        });
```

I am unable to see the print 'after open'
i see below in console.
I/flutter ( 7834): FS:---> openAudioSession

Comment: Yes valid local audio file but it is not even reaching to that instruction. Stuck in _mPlayer.openAudioSession

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use another package [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers)

```
  AudioCache _audioCache;

   _audioCache = AudioCache(
        prefix: "audio/",
        fixedPlayer: AudioPlayer()..setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.STOP));


   _audioCache.play('open-up.mp3');
```

Comment: Not sure why the  other plugin stopped working but  the one you mentioned is working. thanks